# How to store an image from context broker?

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus

I want to send images from various android to context broker, I am not sure how I would go about decoding the image from string format and then storing it to the file system and database respectively. Would I have to develop my own python script or could Cygnus help me out here?

Comment: Are you sure you have the right architecture? context broker is intended for large amounts of small data chunks (like measurements).

Answer (score 1):

Although there are several approaches to transcode a binary file (such an image) into text (e.g. [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)) it doesn't use to be a good idea in Orion Context Broker. Big static files are better placed in an Object Storage service, such [the one that FIWARE provides](http://catalogue.fiware.org/enablers/object-storage-ge-fiware-implementation).

Each file in such systems is identified by an URL. You can use that URL for the attribute values in Orion Context Broker that refer to the given image.

Comment: Someone pointed out to me that it is a bad idea to use object storage for image storage alone. They say that object storage offers so much more, and that using it only to store images is a waste. If however fgalan you disagree with that statement, could you tell me if using the single node installation (http://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/development_saio.html) is a good idea?

Comment: I think that using object storage for storing images or any other binary file is a good practise, as long as you use it as service. Deploying an OS in your own premises probably it is not a good idea. In this case, you could use "lighter" alternatirves, such as HTTP + WebDAV or similar.