# How to enable bigger payloads in Orion? Increase PAYLOAD_MAX_SIZE?

Tags: docker-compose, fiware, fiware-orion

Right now it is not possible to send an entity to Orion with an PAYLOAD_MAX_SIZE >1MB.

```
/****************************************************************************    
*
*
* PAYLOAD_MAX_SIZE - 
*/
#define PAYLOAD_MAX_SIZE (1 * 1024 * 1024) // 1 MB Maximum size of the payload
```

[SourceCode Orion Payload_Max_Size](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/blob/8f2e12356aa023c6e55ee58bcc101c334bd5c8ef/src/lib/common/limits.h#L114)

We have to transfer an entity (including a map/image) through the context broker and the size is > 1MB.

Do you have forseen it as a parameter for the docker compose file? If not, it would be really helpful.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to store an image in the Broker? You should store it in an Object Storage service but not in Orion.

Comment: We need to transfer a MAP (which is a png) and this will be updated couple of times and used by multiple sources. The 1MB FileSize is a real hard limit which we need to change it. 

Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Orion is suited for *context information* which is basically about entities (e.g. a car) and their attributes (e.g. the speed and location asssociated to that car). It is not suited for large binaries (such a PNG file) directly, although the usual pattern is to use the URL as refernce to the binary in a external system where it is stored. Have a look to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31474823/how-to-store-an-image-from-context-broker/31479946#31479946) for more details.

Comment: Our map is *not static*, it will *change over time*. Even a topology for a robot has to be stored inside Orion so that other are able to receive them. The *topology* is an *entity* with *context information*

Comment: Could your edit your question post to include an example of your entity (in JSON) so we can have a better idea of the use case, pls? Thanks!